# Coroutines Handler like behaviour

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

In one part of my application I post runnable to a Handler, then the code inside `run()` executes and posts the same runnable to Handler with `postDelayed()`. This creates something like loop. Is this behaviour achievable with coroutines? I tried to use channel, but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this behaviour achievable with coroutines?

Yes, and in an almost embarrassingly straightforward way:

```
launch(UI) {
    while (!done()) {
        // loop body
        delay(loopDelayMillis)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks and is there a way I can handle multiple messages when one or more of these messages would have this kind of loop behaviour?

Comment: Yes, all of the loops will run "concurrently" on the UI thread, i.e., their individual iterations will be interleaved. `delay()`, of course, is a suspending, not a blocking method.

Comment: Isn't this achievable with actor? I would like to send "commands" to it having an when branch inside deciding what would each command do. And the actor itself would in one branch of when (only one command has this desired behaviour) send the same command but with delay.

Comment: I don't quite follow your description and I also have far less experience with Kotlin actors. My answer pertains to your question as posted.

Comment: Thanks anyway, would it help if I posted some example code?

Comment: That depends :) I'm missing information about your use case that you say motivates the use of actors as opposed to the simple loop I've shown.